# Pandas DataFrame Difference among Rows for Same Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It is difficult to describe the problem in Title. Let me give below example:

I have below dataframe

```
id  value
asd123  2
asd123  4
asd124  15
asd124  32
asd125  2
asd125  3
asd126  5
asd126  14
asd126  22
asd127  7
asd127  17
asd127  30
asd128  23
asd128  28
asd129  3
asd130  25
asd131  56
asd132  3
asd133  53
```

I would need to look for same id group and two consecutive rows in value column difference greater than 5.(value column always asc) If it is just one record, it doesn't need to look for the difference for the value.

I tried adding a sequence column for my DF:

```
id  value   sequence
asd123  2   1
asd123  4   2
asd124  15  1
asd124  32  2
asd125  2   1
asd125  3   2
asd126  5   1
asd126  14  2
asd126  22  3
asd127  7   1
asd127  17  2
asd127  30  3
asd128  23  1
asd128  28  2
asd129  3   1
asd130  25  1
asd131  56  1
asd132  3   1
asd133  53  1
```

Basically, i can drop if sequence = 1 records, for sequence greater than 1, I need to look for the difference of Values column among the rows, if values difference greater than 5, i need to filter out that records. For examples like 3 rows, i need to look two consecutive rows and minus seq 2 - seq 1 values and 3-2, if either results greater than 5, i will need id.

Thank you in advance.

```
df['sequence']=df.groupby('id').cumcount()
df_2=df[df['sequence']>=2]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The expected result is correct, however, the 'value>5' looks like have syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.set_index('id').groupby(level=0).diff().query('value > 5').index.unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['asd124', 'asd126', 'asd127']
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. But baller one-liner. Bravo!

Comment: @jack6e Thank you, I am not sure that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: I think you got it right. Or he wants to use that result to remove those records from his original dataframe. Either way, you solved the difficult part.

Comment: Thank you Scott, the out put is correct, question for 'value>5' , i got error saying 'value' is not defined

Comment: Thank you both, actually, I need to do a math between two consecutive rows, for example, asd126 has 3 values, i have to check if if difference between two connected values greater than 5 or not. Not just value itself.

Comment: I did: df['Diff']=df.groupby(['id'])["value"].diff(1)
df_new=df[df['id']>5] this ways works. Thank you for the help